# Display alert box on submit with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show an alert when a button is clicked, but it is not working for some reason:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<input type = "button" value = "submit">

<script type = "text/javascript" src ="JQuery.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="message.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my jQuery code, I haven't given any id or class to it.

```
<script>
    $(":button").click(function(){
            $(":button").alert("pressed");
            });
</script>
```

Comment: is this script the source of message.js?

Comment: I Have saved the file as message .js on the separate file and then including the file in index.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reference to button for alert. In other word `$(":bottom").alert("pressed")` is meaningless:

```js
$(":button").click(function(){
  alert("pressed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "button" value = "submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no JQuery alert method. You can use the built-in alert method on the Window object:

```
$(":button").click(function(){
        alert("pressed");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing
`$(":button").alert("pressed");`
to

```
alert("pressed");
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

remove all your `JQuery` code and replace it with this one line code  `$(":button").on("click",()=> alert("pressed"))`